# How do you unflatten nodes array to a routing tree path?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, flatten

How do you write a function that will perform an unflattening transformation on a nodes array of objects which represents a directory structure or routing path tree.
Here's an example nodes array:

```
const nodes = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "path": "/home",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "path": "/users",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "path": "/users/alice",
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "path": "/users/bob",
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "path": "/users/alice/posts",
  }
];
```

To transforming an array into the following nested object:

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "path": "/home",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "path": "/users",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "path": "/users/alice",
          "children": [
            {
              "children": [],
              "id": "5",
              "path": "/users/alice/posts"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "path": "/users/bob",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here:

```js
    const nodes = [ { "id": "1", "path": "/home",},{"id": "2","path": "/users",},{"id": "3","path": "/users/alice",},{"id": "4","path": "/users/bob",},{"id": "5","path": "/users/alice/posts",}];
    const tree = {path: "/", children: []};
    nodes.map(t => ({id: t.id, path: t.path.split('/').slice(1)}))
        .sort((a, b) => a.path.length - b.path.length)
        .forEach(t => {
            t.path.slice(0, -1).reduce((a, b) => a.children.find(el => el.path === b), tree).children.push({
                id: t.id,
                path: t.path[t.path.length - 1],
                children: []
            });
        });
    console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. What I did were:

- First create a tree with only the root directory (i.e. `path: '/'`)
- Then, for each node, I will "traverse" it according to its `path`
- I will traverse each directory separated by `/` in each node. Then, I will check if there is already a subtree (i.e. `children`) within the said directory's `children` array. If there isn't, create a new subtree and push it to the array.
- For each directory traversed in node, update the variable `traversed` to store the currently being traversed subtree
- When I reach the final directory of each node, update the directory id to the node id

Here's a working example (the code below works when `paths` are not sorted, i.e. some longer paths with directories that don't exist create said directories):

```js
const nodes = [{ "id": "1", "path": "/home" }, { "id": "2", "path": "/users" }, { "id": "3", "path": "/users/alice" }, { "id": "4", "path": "/users/bob" }, { "id": "5", "path": "/users/alice/posts" }]
const tree = { path: '/', children:[] }

nodes.forEach(node => {
  const dirs = node.path.split('/').slice(1)
  let traversed = tree // Hold the reference of tree
  let totalPath = ``
  
  dirs.forEach((dir, index) => {
    const foundChild = traversed.children.find(child => child.path === `${totalPath}/${dir}`)
    const currSubtree = foundChild ? foundChild : { path: `${totalPath}/${dir}`, children: [] }
    
    if (!foundChild) traversed.children.push(currSubtree)
    if (index === dirs.length - 1) currSubtree.id = node.id
    traversed = currSubtree
    totalPath += `/${dir}`
  })
})

console.log(tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since previous answers do not provide full path for each nested node (and I believe this is what OP wants) here is my take on it:

- sort objects by path length and their id
- for each object split its path
- for each dir of a split path try to find an object within the tree that matches partial path
- `.reduce()` will return last object that matched (or our initial value which is a tree base)
- push initial object into that

```js
const nodes = [
  {"id": "4","path": "/users/bob"},
  {"id": "5","path": "/users/alice/posts"},
  {"id":"6", "path": "/home/somedir/etc"},
  {"id": "2","path": "/users"},
  {"id": "1", "path": "/home"},
  {"id": "3","path": "/users/alice"}
];
const tree = {path: "/", children: []};

nodes.sort((a, b) => (a.path.split('/').length - b.path.split('/').length) || parseInt(a.id) - parseInt(b.id))
  .forEach(node => node.path.split('/').slice(1)
  .reduce(((a, b) => (a.children.find(el => el.path.slice(el.path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) === b) || a)), tree)
  .children.push({id: node.id, path: node.path, children: []}));

console.log(tree);
```

It's worth noting that this code does not create intermediate nodes/paths if they weren't provided, i.e `/home/somedir/etc` will be nested under `/home` because `/home/somedir` doesn't exist in the initial array.